# What is the correct use of als or wie in this case?

Tags: conjunction

While discussing the translation of the following sentence with 2 native German speakers:

> She watched with interest **as** the patch of moisture shrank slowly and vanished.

I suggested:

> Sie schaute mit Interesse zu, **als** der Fleck der Feuchtigkeit langsam schwand und schließlich verschwand.

But they insisted that it should be:

> Sie schaute mit Interesse zu, **wie** der Fleck der Feuchtigkeit langsam schwand und schließlich verschwand.

But if the word "as" were substituted with "when" in the English sentence, the meaning would remain unchanged. So it wasn't clear to me why "als" would not also be correct.

So I put these sentences into Google Translate:

> **When** the patch of moisture shrank slowly and vanished, she watched with interest.

> She watched with interest, **when** the patch of moisture shrank slowly and vanished.

And the results were:

> **Als** der Feuchtigkeitsfleck langsam schrumpfte und verschwand, sah sie interessiert zu.

> Sie beobachtete interessiert, **wie** der Feuchtigkeitsfleck langsam schrumpfte und verschwand.

Can someone identify for me which of these translations is correct and which are not? And if Google Translate is correct, why should the order of the sentence determine the use of als vs. wie?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are all correct. The preferred one depends on what exactly you might want to express or stress. Usually the translation with 'wie' will be more accurate as it expresses the interaction of the activity in the first part to the 2nd part of the sentence. In German 'als' (only) expresses coincidence, but not any other relation:

> Sie schaute mit Interesse zu als der Fleck verschwand

She watched with interest (but not clear what). The patch vanished at the same time. No direct relation beyond temporal coincidence is implied.

> Sie schaute mit Interesse zu wie der Fleck verschwand

She watched with interest as the patch vanished. She really looked with interest at the patch vanishing.

Comment: In short: *wie* = *as*, *als* = *when*. But in a sentence like *She watched with interest, when the patch of moisture shrank slowly and vanished.* it is unclear what was being watched except for the patch, so it might get translated the same as if *as* were used.

Comment: That was somewhat my feeling, too. But I can swear I also came across usage like "As the sun set, the wind calmed down" or similar. So the usage in English is sometimes as unclear as it is also sometimes in German used interchangeably (which probably doesn't make it right in either language to use it interchangeably). But as I'm not a native English speaker, especially not aware of all regional variations there... I'd wanted to address this cautiously

Comment: I'd say the "wie" variant has a strong connotation of "how", whereas "als" gives a connotation of "while".

Answer (score -3):

The probably best explanation comes from the stylist Karl Kraus (from the book "Die Sprache"):

> **Als und wie**
>
> Dem »als« an jener Stelle folgt ein Doppelpunkt:
>
> ich mute ihnen zu ... was so viel bedeutet als: ich verlange von ihnen ...
>
> Diese Setzung schon, die ein Wägen und Messen beinahe graphisch anschaulich macht, könnte den Unterschied erfassen lehren. Wenn er in der Schule so gelehrt wird, daß »als« »nur nach Komparativen und nach dem Wort ›anders‹ und seinen Ableitungen« zu stehen komme, so wird er falsch gelehrt. Richtig ist, daß in solchen Fällen nicht »wie« gebraucht werden kann, »als« jedoch kann auch sonst gebraucht werden. Falsch ist es, zu schreiben, daß ein Ding besser oder anders ist »wie« ein anderes (wiewohl auch Klassiker manchmal nicht besser als so schreiben und Journalisten nicht anders »wie« so schreiben können.) Aber »als«, das einen größeren Geltungsbereich hat als »wie«, wird auch in der positiven Fügung oder scheinbaren Gleichstellung der verglichenen Begriffe gebraucht werden können. In dem zitierten Fall ist es dem »wie« vorzuziehen. Gerade an diesem Beispiel ließe sich der Bedeutungsunterschied auch dann vorstellen, wenn nicht der Doppelpunkt die Prozedur sinnfällig machte, die zum Ausdruck gelangen soll. Gewiß, wenn ich zwei begrifflich analoge Quantitäten verbinden will, so werde ich sie durch »wie« verbinden. Ich will ihre Gleichheit durch den Vergleich darstellen: ein Gegenstand wiegt so viel »wie« ein anderer. Wenn ich aber einen Gegenstand wägen will, so wird er so viel »als« einen Zentner wiegen. Der Wiener Dialekt trifft hier den Unterschied ganz richtig: »Das macht so viel als wie....«, während er sagt, daß ein Ding »so viel wie« ein anderes wiegt. Der Vergleich als solcher ist durch »wie«, das Moment des Maßes durch »als« bezeichnet. »Zumuten«, hieß es, »bedeutet so viel als: verlangen«. Aber bei den Journalisten bedeutet Zumuten so viel »wie« Zutrauen. In jenem Fall sage ich, was es bedeutet. In diesem: daß eines soviel wie das andere bedeutet; daß die Bedeutungen verwechselt werden. (Es ist gehupft »wie« gesprungen. Oder, um in der Sphäre zu bleiben: gedruckt »wie« gelogen.) An jener Stelle unterstützt der Doppelpunkt plastisch den Ausdruck der Messung. Die »klangliche Häßlichkeit« des »wie«, von der der Anfragende spricht, hat einen inneren Grund. Man könnte es dort nicht anwenden, es wäre ein anderer Gedanke, nämlich der: daß ich zwei bereits gemessene und gleich befundene Quantitäten miteinander verbinden, nicht: daß ich Maß oder Gewicht einer Quantität erst bestimmen will. Eine Sache bedeutet so viel »wie« eine andere Sache = sie bedeutet so viel, wie die andere bedeutet; beide bedeuten gleich viel. (Bezogen auf ein Tertium, mit dem beide verglichen gedacht werden.) Eine Sache bedeutet so viel »als« eine andere = sie bedeutet so viel als das, was die andere ist; sie bedeutet die andere. Dort erfolgt der Vergleich zweier Quantitäten, hier der der einen mit dem Gewicht. Hier würde ich sagen, daß ich die eine » mit der andern vergleiche«, dort, daß ich sie »der andern« vergleiche (also Dativ ohne Präposition, zur Bezeichnung des vorweg Übereinstimmenden). Der Bleistift wiegt so viel wie der Federhalter (Vergleich), aber: der Bleistift wiegt zweimal so viel als der Federhalter (Messung). Eine Sache ist so gut »als« möglich: das heißt, daß sie so gut ist, als es möglich ist. Eine Sache ist so gut »wie« möglich: das hieße, daß sie so gut ist, wie sie möglich ist, ebenso gut wie möglich, in demselben bereits gegebenen Maße, oder gut und möglich zugleich.

Comment: The question is asked in English. Most part of your answer is in German. For a couple of reasons, there is an established consensus to post the answer in the language of the question, if possible. Find the reasoning about this here: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1048/should-the-language-of-an-answer-match-the-language-used-in-the-question

Comment: @JonathanScholbach I think most of the text is a quote (and thus not translated, but should be indicated as such).

Comment: Actually i DID indicate it as such (a quote) in the first sentence: " from the stylist Karl Kraus (from the book "Die Sprache")"

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: i think you yourself quoted one or two sources without translating them too, no?

Comment: You did somewhat yes; we have quote tags for a reason though :) I'm not sure whether the original is such unpleasantly readable wall of text, though.

Comment: While I appreciate the depth of insight and detail provided by this answer, it would be clearer to me, a struggling student of German, if the gist could be summarized in English, just so I could look for milestone points as I endeavor to understand the German.

Comment: I don't remember if I quoted a German text in an answer to an English question without translating it. If I did, please tell me, so I can translate the quote there. The baseline here is: The answer consists basically of the quote alone. Answers should be in the language of the question.